# append with if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, append

I need use if (else if, else) statement  with many .append() functions. Just like you can see in my example... Is it possible ? Thank you.

```
 $('body')
      .append($('<div>', {class: 'wrapper'})

           // if statement comes here
           .append($('<div>')
                .append($('<form>')
                     .append($('<input>'))
                 )
            )

           // else if statement comes here
           .append($('<div>')
                .append($('<form>')
                     .append($('<input>'))
                 )
            )

           // else statement comes here
           .append($('<div>')
                .append($('<form>')
                     .append($('<input>'))
                 )
            )

            // end if

       );
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, when you see a line starting with a dot, it is actually a function call.

```
$('body')
  .append($('<div>', {class: 'wrapper'});
// Is equivalent to:
$('body').append($('<div>', {class: 'wrapper'});
```

Here it does not bring anything, but mixed with "chaining", then it becomes clearer to read. "chaining" is used in many programming languages. What you do is that when a method does not need to return anything particular, you return the object itself.

JQuery does this a lot. For example `$('body').width()` returns the width, but the `append` is what is called a method with "side effects". Its purpose is not to return anything but to change the object itself. It could have returned `null`. But the fact that it returns itself allows you to chain method calls instead of repeating an object each time.

```
$('body').append($('<div>', {class: 'wrapper'}).append($('<div>', {class: 'inside'});
// Is equivalent to:
$('body').append($('<div>', {class: 'wrapper'});
$('body').append($('<div>', {class: 'inside'});
```

The other advantage of chaining is that you don't need to recreate a jQuery object each time. You see my example above is not really good be cause I use `$('body')` twice which does not look that bad, but if you do this many times in a function that runs often, it can be quite expensive. I should have saved what `$('body')` returns in a variable.

You probably can see where I am going now. You cannot break the chain of method calls like you suggested. But you can save your `$('body')` and not use chaining.

```
var $body = $('body');
$body.append($('<div>', {class: 'wrapper'});

if (condition) {
  $body.append($('<div>');
  $body.append($('<form>');
}
```

This answers your particular question. Further than this your code example seems to suggest that you want nesting, so it is going to be a little more tedious to organize, but you can find many stackoverflow questions related to nested `append`in jQuery.

Comment: Thnak you for your answer :) I know and understand that code... I wrote it... As you can see, I have many ".appned()" in my code. It's hard to separate it... That is the reason, why I'm asking question. If somebody has solution to include "if statement" in  code like this... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use statement with many .append(), try this

```
 var condition= 1;
    var html1 = new Array();
    if(condition==1)
    {
      html1.push("<div class='item1'>");
    }
    else if(condition==2)
    {
        html1.push("<div class='item1'>");
    }

    $('body').append(html1.join(''));
```